# Difference between $S_{xx}$ and $s_{xx}$

Tags: statistics

What is the difference between $S_{xx}$ and $s_{xx}$?
I understand that $S_{xx}$ = $\Sigma_{i=1}^n(x_i - \bar{x})^2$ but how does this formula compare to the formula for $s_{xx}$?

Comment: I have never seen either of these pieces of notation before, and in particular have no idea what $s_{xx}$ is, although it looks like $S_{xx}$ is just the sample variance. Can you also provide a formula for $s_{xx}$?

Answer (score 0):

$$  SS_{xx}  =\Sigma_{i=1}^n(x_i - \bar{x})^2$$ and $$s_{xx} =\Sigma_{i=1}^n x_i^2$$

Answer (score 0):

$S_{xx}$ and $s_{xx}$ both are standard deviation but $s_{xx}$ is **unbiased** estimator of $\sigma$. $$S_{xx}=\frac{\Sigma_{i=1}^n(x_i - \bar{x})^2}{n}$$ and $$s_{xx}=\frac{\Sigma_{i=1}^n(x_i - \bar{x})^2}{n-1}$$